# For which $n$, is any continuous map from $S^n$ to $S^1 \times S^1$ nulhomotopic.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

For which $n$,  where $n$ is a positive integer, is any continuous map from $S^n$ to $S^1 \times S^1$ nulhomotopic.

If every continuous map from some $S^n$ to $S^1 \times S^1$ was nulhomotopic, would this not mean that they had the same fundamental group? Since the fundamental group of $S^n$ is trivial for $n\geq 2$, and $\pi_1 (S^1) = \mathbb{Z}$ and $\pi_1 (S^1 \times S^1) = \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$, is there no such positive integer?

Thanks!

Comment: A continuous map $S^n\to S^1\times S^1$ is given by two continuous maps $S^n\to S^1$, namely its two components (technically, its composites with the two projections of the product). Treating these two components individually, it suffices to know that the higher homotopy groups of $S^1$ are trivial.

Comment: @AndreasBlass This is really not that much easier than doing this directly...

Comment: To answer your latter question, no. Fundamental group is about maps from $S^1$, not $S^n$. An example that'll make you feel more comfortable is this: Every map from $S^1$ to $S^2$ is nullhomotopic, but their $\pi_1$'s are not the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every $n$ bigger than $1,$ which is another way of saying that the higher homotopy groups of $S^1 \times S^1$ are trivial, which is true because the universal covering space is $\mathbb{R}^2,$ which is acyclic.

Comment: What about $n=0$ ;)

Comment: Well, notice that $0 \leq 1,$ so I did not cover that case. There is certainly more than one homotopy class of maps then...

Comment: $\pi_0(S^1\times S^1)=\{[c]\}$ because $S^1\times S^1$ is path-connected.

Comment: @DanielRust Oops, I was thinking about maps into $S_0,$ for some strange reason.

Comment: Ah, yes the $0$th cohomotopy set $\pi^0(X)=[X,S^0]$ of a non-empty connected space $X$ is always of cardinality two, pretty much from definition.

Comment: @DanielRust Yes, exactly. I guess I was trying to make Steven Gubkin's comment more humorous :)